# Is there a way to access previous CXF message?

Tags: java, cxf, cxfrs, cxf-client

I know that I can access current message with:

```
PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage()
```

But when cxf creates new message, I am losing two headers from previous exchange.
Is there a way to somehow access old message, or pass headers from old to new message (so I aint gonna lose required data)?

Comment: CXF Message is stored into ThreadLocal, so any new message using the same thread probably overwrite it, and the data should be cleaned after processing. What information do you need to maintain? Between two different requests or between request and response?

Comment: It's between two requests - Im making a call to different cxf proxy client - thats when new message is being created

Comment: Then you should not assume that the message will be available after the first request. Store the needed data yourself, for example using ThreadLocal, if the second request is executed in the same thread